# Error message: h5py.h5py_warnings.H5pyDeprecationWarning: dataset.value has been deprecated. Use dataset[()] instead

Tags: python, bioinformatics, h5py

I'm tring to run [mbin](https://mbin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) for methylation analysis. But get error message: `h5py.h5py_warnings.H5pyDeprecationWarning: dataset.value has been deprecated. Use dataset[()] instead.`
for several attempts, while trying to extract control IPDs with buildcontrols.
 
Environment:

- mbin version: 1.1.1
- Python version:2.7.12
- Operating System: centOS
- running under virtualenv

I thought it was, again, caused by version.
What I've tried:
I tried on a server with both python 3 and 2. And specified virtualenv to use python 2 as interpreter. mbin was successfully installed, but buidlcontrols didn't.

```
(virtualenv_for_mbin) [yx@localhost virtualenv_for_mbin]$ buildcontrols -i --procs=4 --control_pkl_name=control_means_190201.pkl /data1/yuxiao/userdata1/jobs/016/016504/data/aligned_reads.cmp.h5
2019-02-01 23:36:31 [INFO] Initiating dictionary of all possible motifs...
2019-02-01 23:36:31 [INFO]   - Adding 256 4-mer motifs...
2019-02-01 23:36:31 [INFO] Done: 256 possible contiguous motifs

2019-02-01 23:36:31 [INFO]   - Adding 1024 5-mer motifs...
2019-02-01 23:36:31 [INFO] Done: 1536 possible contiguous motifs

2019-02-01 23:36:31 [INFO]   - Adding 4096 6-mer motifs...
2019-02-01 23:36:32 [INFO] Done: 7680 possible contiguous motifs

2019-02-01 23:36:32 [INFO]   - Adding bipartite motifs to search space...
2019-02-01 23:36:33 [INFO] Done: 194560 possible bipartite motifs

2019-02-01 23:36:33 [INFO] 
2019-02-01 23:36:33 [INFO] Preparing to create new control data in ctrl_tmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data2/Software/virtualenv_for_mbin/bin/buildcontrols", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(launch())
  File "/data2/Software/virtualenv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mbin/controls.py", line 20, in launch
    extract_controls(opts, control_aln_fn)
  File "/data2/Software/virtualenv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mbin/controls.py", line 40, in extract_controls
    opts           = controls.scan_WGA_aligns()
  File "/data2/Software/virtualenv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mbin/controls.py", line 352, in scan_WGA_aligns
    reader = openIndexedAlignmentFile(self.control_aln_fn)
  File "/data2/Software/virtualenv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbcore/io/opener.py", line 52, in openIndexedAlignmentFile
    return CmpH5Reader(fname, sharedIndex=sharedIndex)
  File "/data2/Software/virtualenv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbcore/io/align/CmpH5IO.py", line 729, in __init__
    self._loadAlignmentInfo(sharedIndex)
  File "/data2/Software/virtualenv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbcore/io/align/CmpH5IO.py", line 745, in _loadAlignmentInfo
    rawAlignmentIndex = self.file["/AlnInfo/AlnIndex"].value
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/data2/Software/virtualenv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 313, in value
    "Use dataset[()] instead.", H5pyDeprecationWarning)
h5py.h5py_warnings.H5pyDeprecationWarning: dataset.value has been deprecated. Use dataset[()] instead.
```

I checked python version:

```
(virtualenv_for_mbin) [yx@localhost virtualenv_for_mbin]$ python -V
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

So, I immediately tried to run a new virtualenv.

```
[yx@localhost Software]$ mkdir venv_tmp
[yx@localhost Software]$ cd venv_tmp/
[yx@localhost venv_tmp]$ virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 .
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2.7
New python executable in /data2/Software/venv_tmp/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /data2/Software/venv_tmp/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
[yx@localhost venv_tmp]$ . bin/activate
(venv_tmp) [yx@localhost venv_tmp]$ python -V
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Then, I turned to another server.....with only python 2.7 installed.

```
(venv_for_mbin) [yuxiao@localhost data_tmp]$ buildcontrols -i --procs=4 --control_pkl_name=control_means_190202.pkl aligned_reads.cmp.h5
2019-02-02 11:06:16 [INFO] Initiating dictionary of all possible motifs...
2019-02-02 11:06:16 [INFO]   - Adding 256 4-mer motifs...
2019-02-02 11:06:16 [INFO] Done: 256 possible contiguous motifs

2019-02-02 11:06:16 [INFO]   - Adding 1024 5-mer motifs...
2019-02-02 11:06:16 [INFO] Done: 1536 possible contiguous motifs

2019-02-02 11:06:16 [INFO]   - Adding 4096 6-mer motifs...
2019-02-02 11:06:16 [INFO] Done: 7680 possible contiguous motifs

2019-02-02 11:06:16 [INFO]   - Adding bipartite motifs to search space...
2019-02-02 11:06:18 [INFO] Done: 194560 possible bipartite motifs

2019-02-02 11:06:18 [INFO] 
2019-02-02 11:06:18 [INFO] Preparing to create new control data in ctrl_tmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data1/yuxiao/venv_for_mbin/bin/buildcontrols", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(launch())
  File "/data1/yuxiao/venv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mbin/controls.py", line 20, in launch
    extract_controls(opts, control_aln_fn)
  File "/data1/yuxiao/venv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mbin/controls.py", line 40, in extract_controls
    opts           = controls.scan_WGA_aligns()
  File "/data1/yuxiao/venv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mbin/controls.py", line 352, in scan_WGA_aligns
    reader = openIndexedAlignmentFile(self.control_aln_fn)
  File "/data1/yuxiao/venv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbcore/io/opener.py", line 52, in openIndexedAlignmentFile
    return CmpH5Reader(fname, sharedIndex=sharedIndex)
  File "/data1/yuxiao/venv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbcore/io/align/CmpH5IO.py", line 729, in __init__
    self._loadAlignmentInfo(sharedIndex)
  File "/data1/yuxiao/venv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbcore/io/align/CmpH5IO.py", line 745, in _loadAlignmentInfo
    rawAlignmentIndex = self.file["/AlnInfo/AlnIndex"].value
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/data1/yuxiao/venv_for_mbin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 313, in value
    "Use dataset[()] instead.", H5pyDeprecationWarning)
h5py.h5py_warnings.H5pyDeprecationWarning: dataset.value has been deprecated. Use dataset[()] instead.
(venv_for_mbin) [yuxiao@localhost data_tmp]$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
```

Still got the same error message. And I'm here hoping someone can help me. Thx a lot.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/fanglab/mbin/issues/8)<br/> 
I finally got this work. Replacing every *.value with "[()] " in CmpH5IO.py in line 745, 768, 831, as prompt

Answer (score 22):

As you said, you need to use the new way of getting scalar values out.
The `.value` syntax still works, but who wants to see pink warnings in Jupyter?

The message is not very intuitive, as isn't the syntax. So I will spell this out here - you have a d5py.File called f:

```
>>> f = h5py.File('temp.h5')
>>> f['path/to/scalar'] = 5
>>> f['path/to/scalar'].value
(...)\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py:313: H5pyDeprecationWarning: dataset.value has been deprecated. Use dataset[()] instead. "Use dataset[()] instead.", H5pyDeprecationWarning)
5
```

"Use dataset[()] instead" means literally "use the indexing (`__getitem__`) operator, and pass to it an empty `tuple` (`()`). So the last line should read:

```
>>> f['path/to/scalar'][()]
5
```

If you feel this is a bit of a strange, exotic notation, I can only empathize.

But it makes some sense - the `numpy.shape` of scalar values is in fact `()`.

Comment: yeah this seems like a bad move