# Why can I process a large file only when I don't fix HDF5 deprecation warning?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, hdf5

After receiving the `H5pyDeprecationWarning: dataset.value has been deprecated. Use dataset[()] instead.` [warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489830/error-message-h5py-h5py-warnings-h5pydeprecationwarning-dataset-value-has-been), I changed my code to:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np 

f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5', mode='r')
foo = f['foo']
bar = f['bar']
N, C, H, W = foo.shape. # (8192, 3, 1080, 1920)
data_foo = np.array(foo[()]) # [()] equivalent to .value
```

and when I tried to read a (not so) big file of images, I got a `Killed: 9` on my terminal, my process was killed because it was consuming too much memory, on the last line of the code, despite that archaic comment of mine there . .

However, my original code:

```
f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5', mode='r')
data_foo = f.get('foo').value
# script's logic after that worked, process not killed
```

worked just fine, except from the issued warning..

Why did my code work?

Comment: This line returns a h5py object: `foo = f['foo']`. Dataset objects behave like NumPy arrays (for example, you can slice foo).  If you want a NumPy array, use `foo_arr = f['foo'][:]` or `foo_arr = foo[:]` after you created the `foo` object. Note `.value()` works like `[:]`, but is a deprecated method. Use NumPy slicing notation instead.

Comment: One other thing...dataset objects have a memory usage advantage over NumPy arrays. Unlike a NumPy array, when you access the object, you do NOT read the entire dataset into memory. Create the object, then access slices as you need data. You created an array with ALL of the data -- that's why your process consumed so much memory.

Comment: Hmm I think I get your point @kcw78, didn't know that critical difference between numpy and dataset object. I believe you could transform your comments into an answer, if you like. Or if you feel that my question is uninteresting, I'd delete it..

Comment: Your question is important to highlight the difference between numpy arrays and dataset objects. They look and act very similar (by design). It doesn't matter when the datasets are small. It is critically important when the dataset is too large to fit in memory (your situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain what your code is doing, and why you are getting memory errors. First some HDF5/h5py basics. (The h5py docs are an excellent starting point. Check here: [h5py QuickStart](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html))

`foo = f['foo']` and `foo = f.get('foo')` both return a h5py dataset object named 'foo'.(Note: it's more common to see this as `foo = f['foo']`, but nothing wrong with the `get()` method.)  A dataset object **is not the same** as a NumPy array. Datasets behave like NumPy arrays; both have a shape and a data type, and support array-style slicing. However, when you access a dataset object, you do not read all of the data into memory. As a result, they require less memory to access. This is important when working with large datasets!

This statement returns a Numpy array: `data_foo = f.get('foo').value`. The preferred method is `data_foo = f['foo'][:]`. (NumPy slicing notation is the way to return a NumPy array from a dataset object. As you discovered, `.value` is deprecated.)
This also returns a Numpy array: `data_foo = foo[()]` (assuming foo is defined as above).
So, when you enter this equation `data_foo = np.array(foo[()])` you are creating a new NumPy array from another array (`foo[()]` is the input object). I suspect your process was killed because the amount of memory to create a copy of a (8192, 3, 1080, 1920) array exceeded your system resources. That statement will work for small datasets/arrays. However, it's not good practice.

Here's an example to show how to use the different methods (h5py dataset object vs NumPy array).

```
h5f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5', mode='r')

# This returns a h5py object:
foo_ds = h5f['foo']
# You can slice to get elements like this:
foo_slice1 = foo_ds[0,:,:,:] # first row
foo_slice2 = foo_ds[-1,:,:,:] # last row

# This is the recommended method to get a Numpy array of the entire dataset:
foo_arr = h5f['foo'][:]
# or, referencing h5py dataset object above
foo_arr = foo_ds[:] 
# you can also create an array with a slice
foo_slice1 = h5f['foo'][0,:,:,:] 
# is the same as (from above):
foo_slice1 = foo_ds[0,:,:,:]
```